# Is there a faster way of check every single string at the end of a website

Tags: python-3.7

I'm trying to brute force my friend's website and I wanted to know the quickest way to check every single possibility. His website ends in an eight-character string (Eg 1_c2F3c$). The way I am doing it right now is with a bunch of nested for loops but it would take way too long. Is there any faster way?

Edit:

```
import urllib.request
char = ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '0', '.', ',', '<', '>', '?', '/', ';', ':', '[', ']', '{', '}', '|', '`', '~', '!', '@', '#', '$', '%', '^', '&', '*', '(', ')', '_', '-', '+', '=', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z']
for a in char:
    for b in char:
        for c in char:
            for d in char:
                for e in char:
                    for f in char:
                        for g in char:
                            for h in char:
                                try:
                                    urllib.request.urlopen("https://galacticacid.wixsite.com/{}".format(a+b+c+d+e+f+g+h).getcode())
                                    print(a+b+c+d+e+f+g+h)
                                except:
                                    pass
```

This would take around 208 years to compute (because every error takes nearly no time).

Comment: Please provide the code you are using

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried

timeit as in:
e.g.

```
% timeit data_rec . age
```

1000000 loops, best of 3: 241 ns per loop
100000 loops, best of 3: 4.61 µs per loop
100000 loops, best of 3: 7.27 µs per loop

e.g.
We can compute the same result via pd.eval by constructing the
expression as a string: In

```
[ 8 ]:     % timeit pd . eval ( 'df1 + df2 + df3 + df4' ) 
            10 loops, best of 3:       42.2 ms per loop
```

Comment: I don't understand